# Ember 1.12 deprecation warning about The `initializer` API

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm upgrading an ember/ember-cli application to ember 1.12. I'm now receiving the following deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION: `lookup` was called on a Registry. The `initializer` API no longer receives a container, 
and you should use an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. 
See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers for more details.
```

Looking at the example, I see that things like the following:

```
App.initializer({
  name: "clock",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.register("clock:main", Clock);
    var clock = container.lookup("clock:main");
    clock.setStartTime(Date.now());
  }
});
```

Should be changed to:

```
App.initializer({
  name: "clock",

  initialize: function(registry, application) {
    application.register("clock:main", Clock);
  }
});

App.instanceInitializer({
  name: "clock",

  initialize: function(instance) {
    var clock = instance.container.lookup("clock:main");
    clock.setStartTime(Date.now());
  }
});
```

But I don't have anything like that code at all. What in an ember-cli 0.2.5 application would cause this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data is most likely causing the issue, I saw it yesterday on one of my apps, you can checkout the stack trace and likely see who the culprit is.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3051

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. It seems that it is saying that the issue has already been fixed in ember-data. I'm using ember-data `1.0.0-beta.17`. Will this go away on its own?

Comment: If you look lower in the github issue they state it isn't fixed yet, and yes, once they fix up ED it will go away, nothing you'll need to worry about unless you attempt to update Ember w/o Ember Data

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in **ember-data v1.0.0-beta.19**, I changed the version of ember-data in my **bower.json** file using v1.0.0-beta.19, then I ran bower install, and finally run my ember application. The deprecated warning messages were gone.